# How can I connect to CiviGrant users?

Tags: civigrant

I am looking for users of CiviGrant who use CiviGrant to administer grants once they have been awarded. We are a new(ish) grant-giving body who already use Civi for managing events and grant applications, and are considering extending our Civi use beyond the application and decision-making stages.

I am looking for organisations who would be willing to talk to us about how they use the CiviGrant system, and what advice they would give. All info would be in confidence.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for CiviGrant users, please include your contact info.
I'm also looking to connect with other CiviGrant users to share tips etc. I can be reached at edith (at) mrgfoundation.org.

Blog post about connecting to CiviGrant users is at:
https://civicrm.org/blog/edith-casterline/calling-all-users-of-civigrant